# how to update parent picklist when child picklist changes

Tags: apex

I have a master detail relationship between `Installation__c` and `Account`. and relation field between `Installation__c`  & `Account` is `Site__c` (API name).
I have a picklist (Time Zone) value on `Account` and `Installation__c` that are identical.
There are 5 values for the picklist.

Whenever the picklist value changes on `Installation__c` , I want to update the picklist value on `Account`  by using apex code only. But i'm getting null value at  `insert accountstoUpdate;` line.

My apex class:

```
public class AccountTimeZoneUpdate {
    public static void accountTimeZone(List<Installation__c> newlist){ 
        set<Id> insId = new set<Id>();
        for(Installation__c inst : newList){
            insId.add(inst.id); 
        } 
        List<Installation__c> instList = [select id,Time_Zone__c Name from Installation__c];
        system.debug('installation list:'+instList);

        List<Account> accList = [select id,Time_Zone__c,name from  Account where Time_Zone__c =: null];

        system.debug('installation list:'+instList);
        List<Account> accountstoUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for(Installation__c insVar:instList){
            for(Account a: accList){
                //Account acc = new Account();
                if(insVar.Time_Zone__c != null && insVar.Time_Zone__c != '') {
                    a.Time_Zone__c = insVar.Time_Zone__c;
                    accountstoUpdate.add(a);
                }
            }
        }
        insert accountstoUpdate;
        system.debug('accountstoUpdate time:'+accountstoUpdate);
    }
}
```

My trigger:

```
trigger InstallationTrigger on Installation__c (after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
        AccountTimeZoneUpdate.accountTimeZone(trigger.new);
    }
```

Comment: Your second query, the one on `Account` looks very strange to me. Since your two objects are in a relationship (the type doesn't really matter), shouldn't you be querying Accounts based on the `Site__c` field you told us about (rather than whether the time zone field is null)? The nested for loop you have is also likely a semantic error. You're iterating over all your Installations, and then all your queried Accounts, and setting time zone regardless of whether the Installation is related to that particular Account. You'd be getting "duplicate id in list" if you had any accounts to update.

Comment: There's a way to avoid the second query altogether, but for now I think you should focus on what your requirements are, and evaluating whether this code meets those requirements or not. Another thing to consider is how will you deal with multiple `Installation__c` records being related to a single `Account`. Do you have something in place to prevent that situation? If you don't have questions about the questions I've asked, then you should [edit] your question to include additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many things in your code that needs to be corrected.

- There is no need to query again for `Installation` as you will get those records as parameter from your trigger i.e. as `Trigger.New`
- You are querying all the Accounts where `Time_Zone__c` is null which is incorrect, instead you should get the `AccountId's` from `Installation` object and query only those records which are related to the `Installation` records which are in transaction. Or else, you can update the `Accounts` without having to query (as long as you have `Id` of `Account`) as shown in the code below.
- You are looping through all the `Account` records and assigning the `Time_Zone__c` of random `Installation's` record to `Account's` `Time_Zone__c` field without checking if it the correct `Account` that is related to that respective `Installation`.

I would suggest you to follow below steps in order to meet your requirements

1. Looping through the `Trigger.New` variable that is passed as parameter.
2. Checking if it assigned to an `Account` and also checking if the value of `Time_Zone__c` is not null or not empty.
3. Then creating an instance of `Account` with `Id` from `Installation` object or getting it from map as you might have multiple `Installation's` associated to same `Account` which might result in duplicates in `List` or you should add a business logic on how to deal if multiple `Installation's` with different `Time_Zone__c` are associated to single `Account`. The code below, updates the Time_Zone__c with the latest associated `Installation's` `Time_Zone__c` in the list.

Below code should help you in getting started with the things

```
public class AccountTimeZoneUpdate{
    public static void accountTimeZone(List newlist){
        Map<Id, Account> accountstoUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Installation__c install : newlist){
            if(install.Site__c!=null && install.Time_Zone__c != null && && install.Time_Zone__c != ''){
                Account acc = accountstoUpdate.containsKey(install.Site__c) ? accountstoUpdate.get(install.Site__c) : new Account(Id = install.Site__c);
                acc.Time_Zone__c = install.Time_Zone__c;
                accountstoUpdate.put(acc.Id, acc);
            }
        }
        update accountstoUpdate.values();
    }
}
```